# What the name of the part of the character that holds the counters and the eyes in a stencil typeface?

Tags: typography, typefaces

Is the a name to the shape that connects the outside of a stencil letter to its interior enabling the letter to be cut through and retain its counters.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's called a *bridge*.

[image: Bridge]

Source: [*Stencil* on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil)